# ! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined

Tags: beamer, unicode, input-encodings

I'm new to Latex espacially Beamer, I am working on my Thesis presentation in French and these letters always give me a hard time since yesterday when I compile that error in the title occurs, I replaced utf8 by utf8x, still no changes, I added this

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar} 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFD}{?????}
```

commands which I read a question in this forum to reveal the letters that causes this error but did not work in my case, here is the code below, please help me to fix this issue, thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer} 

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Footer section
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{footlinerule}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!25!bg}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.5ex,dp=0ex,center]{footlinerule}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.6ex,dp=0ex,center]{empty}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in
head/foot}%
  \insertshortauthor\hspace{1em}(\insertshortinstitute)
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=2ex,right]{date in head/foot}%

    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Report title
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\author{Me}
\title{application web pour gestion des filtres}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{logo.png}} 
\institute[ESSECT]{ESSECT} 
\date{18 mai 2015} 
\subtitle{Rapport du projet fin d’étude}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%sommaire automatique
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamerfont{myTOC}{series=\bfseries,size=\Large}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sommaire}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections, pausesubsections]
  \end{frame} 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

\frametitle{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

\frametitle{Cadre du projet et l'étude de l'éxistant}
\section[]{Cadre du projet et l'étude de l'existant}
\subsection{Introduction}
Dans ce niveau on va comprendre le domaine ou le metier de l'entreprise et des personnes qui y travaillent pour mieux satisfaire leurs besoins. Il s'agit aussi de construire
l'organigramme de l'organisation l'étudiée.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsection{Cadre du stage}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Environnement du stage}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Historique}
\subsubsection{Principales missions}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsection{L'organigramme}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsection{Étude de l'éxistant}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Déscription}

\subsubsection{Analyse de l'éxistant}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Problématiques}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Solution envisagée}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsection{Méthodologie de developpement et conception}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Modèle de conception}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Langage UML}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\subsubsection{Approche en Cascade}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Conclusion}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\section{Capture des besoins}
\end{frame}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Extra slides that won't effect my page numbering
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\appendix 
\begin{frame}{First Extra slide}
...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\def\newblock{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your file encoded as UTF-8?  (This is not done by `inputenc` but by your editor).  And it's likely that you could reduce the code example to a single frame which would reproduce the problem.

Comment: uncommenting all the section commands as discussed in your previous question, everything runs just fine. On the other hand, i have often seen this connected to the bibliography. A file we don't have.

Comment: Thank you for your replay @AlanMunn but I know exactly what frame is causing me this error which is the second one, and I already have a report  class vesion of my thesis which I used the same language packages and just worked fine, but in Beamer I could not figure out where the issue is.

Comment: @Johannes_B I did exactly what you said the earlier error is fixed when I put the sectionnals outside the frames and commented the frames as you showed me still the error is there, Thank you

Comment: Can you update your example, so we see exactly, what code you are currently running? If none of us can reproduce what you see, it is really hard to suggest any further stuff.